# Is it possible to pass a rank-0 tensor to LibraryLink?

Tags: librarylink

There is such a thing as a rank-0 MTensor.  It's mentioned [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/ref/callback/MSparseArray_getImplicitValue.html). Can we pass such an object to a LibraryFunction?  How?

This question is mostly out of curiosity, and not practical need.  But it might solve this:

- [Is it possible to pass a "shared" integer in librarylink?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58114/12)

What I tried:

It is possible to [`LibraryFunctionLoad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LibraryFunctionLoad.html) a function with an argument type of `{Integer, 0, "Shared"}`.  It is possible to load the function like this.  But when trying to pass an integer to it, i.e. simply `a = 1`, then `fun[a]` instead of `a = {1}` then `fun[a]`, it gives an error:

> LibraryFunction::cfsa: Argument 1 at position 2 should be a machine-size integer.